# How to add syntax styling to Windows 10 Code Writer

Tags: ampscript

I'm quite liking Window's new Code Writer for quickly editing the various files that go along with a Salesforce + Marketing Cloud project (usually, SQL, JS, HTML, and AmpScript).

I would like to add a syntax style for AmpScript. Is this possible with Window's Code Writer?

If not, are there other solutions similar to Code Writer that would allow a custom syntax to be added?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so. Windows UWP applications have limitations on how they can be extended (a consequence of sandboxing).

[Since late 2016, UWP apps can have "App extensions"](https://mtaulty.com/2016/08/03/windows-10-anniversary-update-app-extensions-and-app-services/) that work like plugins, but still need approval from the Microsoft App Store and the host application needs to permit it in the first place - and from what I can see in the Code Writer app this isn't possible.

If you want a lightweight but powerful editor I think you're better-off using Notepad++ or a heavier editor like VS Code which has a considerably larger ecosystem of plugins, [including one for AMPScript already](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergey-agadzhanov.AMPscript).